# I want to save new file and create file in new folder in 'Documents'

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to save file to 'MyDocuments', but I don't want user to have it cluttered with a bunch of other files that may already be in there, so I want it to save to a new folder called "DriverLog".  I have tried putting SpecialFolders("MyDocuments\DriverLog\") but says it does not exist.

Here is my code:

```
Sub SaveBook()
'----------------------------------------------------
'Save File to Hard Drive
'----------------------------------------------------
Dim sFile As String
sFile = Range("G2").Value & "_DriverLog" & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments\") & sFile, FileFormat:=52

MsgBox ("This has been saved as '") & CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments\") & sFile & ("' in your documents folder.")


End Sub
```

Code works to save file by itself no problem... I just can't make the new folder.

Comment: Use the [Dir function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) to check if the `DriverLog` folder already exists and if not then create it with the [MkDir statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement)

Comment: it's not clear, where is the new folder name ?

Comment: tigeravatar has the right idea.  I guess I'm not completely sure on how that code will look.  Trying to do this quick for a tight deadline (aren't they all tight) to set it up.  If I can't figure it out, I'll just leave as a file, but would be nice to put in it's own file.  so basically an iff statement.  Also, would I put the If block totally before the whole file create and then instead of my documents, you would put in the complete filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine is a simplified version of the code.

```
'----------------------------------------------------
'Save File to Hard Drive
'----------------------------------------------------
Dim sFile       As String
Dim sPath       As String

sPath = "C:\Users\User\MyDocuments\DriverLog"

sFile = Range("G2").Value & "_DriverLog" & ".xlsm"

If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then  'Added This line to create new folder
    MkDir (sPath)
End If


ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & "\" & sFile


MsgBox ("This has been saved as ") & sPath & "\" & sFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.  The `CreateDirectory` Sub is a common routine I use for this task.

```
Sub SaveBook()
'----------------------------------------------------
'Save File to Hard Drive
'----------------------------------------------------

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sPS As String

    sPS = Application.PathSeparator
    sPath = Environ("UserProfile") & sPS & "Documents" & sPS & "DriverLog" & sPS
    CreateDirectory sPath
    If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Couldn't create the path due to invalid or inaccessible location
    sFile = Range("G2").Value & "_DriverLog" & ".xlsm"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & sFile, FileFormat:=52

    MsgBox ("This has been saved as '") & sPath & sFile & ("' in your documents folder.")

End Sub

Sub CreateDirectory(ByVal arg_sFolderpath As String)

    If Len(Dir(arg_sFolderpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        Dim sPS As String
        sPS = Application.PathSeparator

        Dim sBuildPath As String
        Dim vFolder As Variant
        For Each vFolder In Split(arg_sFolderpath, sPS)
            If Len(vFolder) > 0 Then
                If Len(sBuildPath) = 0 Then sBuildPath = vFolder Else sBuildPath = sBuildPath & sPS & vFolder
                If Len(Dir(sBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    MkDir sBuildPath
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Len(Dir(sBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                        MsgBox "[" & sBuildPath & "] is either invalid or unreachable.", , "Create Directory Error"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next vFolder
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect... exactly what I wanted!